# Hibernate ManyToMany add value when exist in another table

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, spring-data

I have tables with @ManyToMany relationship. I get exception "detached entity passed to persist" when i try to add value in tables Employees.First i created some data in Outpost. How to add employee? Here is my code.

Employees

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employees")
public class EmployeeEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
private Integer employeeId;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String sureName;

@Column
private Long liferayUserId;

@Column
private String phone;

@Column
private String email;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "Employee_Outpost", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "outpost_id") })
private List<OutpostEntity> outposts;
```

Outpost

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Outpost")
public class OutpostEntity implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7782359215536098452L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "outpost_id", nullable = false)
private Integer outpostID;

@Column
private String province;

@Column
private String city;

@Column
private String postCode;

@Column
private String street;

@Column
private String phone;

@Column
private String openingHours;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "outpostID", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<ShipperEntity> shippers;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "outposts", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<EmployeeEntity> employees = new HashSet<EmployeeEntity>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "outpost", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<AreaEntity> areas = new HashSet<AreaEntity>();
```

Function

```
EmployeeEntity employee = new EmployeeEntity(model.getName(),
model.getSurename(), model.getPhone(), model.getEmail(),
newUserId, outposts);
employeeJpaRepository.save(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran into `PersistentObjectException` because your `outposts` is in the detached state. Invoke a `employeeJpaRepository.merge(outposts);` before you invoke `employeeJpaRepository.save(employee);` will help.

Introduction of `merge()`:

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return
>   it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become
>   associated with the session. This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="merge".

Comment: But I don't have method merge in employeeJpaRepository.
@Repository
public interface EmployeeJpaRepository extends
  PagingAndSortingRepository<EmployeeEntity, Integer> {

}

Comment: I got solution. I Added @Transactional annotation over my method.

Comment: @user3084292 oh ya...I think that's another approach.